# Enable alpha-numeric keyboard shortcuts under IntelliJ IDEA's keymap(s)

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have a keyboard with the alpha-numeric. I use `Linux` with `GNOME`, and within `IntelliJ IDEA` I can't find an easy way to make all these keys to work as they usually would (as far as I remember) under `Windows`.

There are different keymaps: `Windows`, `GNOME`, etc. By default not a single one provided works with the alpha-numeric keyboard. I usually have to *remap* them by searching <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd> and/or finding the actions by shortcuts, then finally remapping all the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> combinations, etc.

Is there a way to configure the alpha-numeric keys in a straightforward way? I mean by activating something or installing a plugin, instead of configuring them one by one.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206345169/comments/360001397840